# How to toggle group while maintaining sub-toggles

Tags: qgis, group-layer

In QGIS:

I work with large projects in which I have many groups. Often I need to only visualise part of a group. However if I want to toggle off a group and later toggle it on again, all layers in that group are automatically visible. Is there a way to maintain the selection of layers I had visible?

E.g.I want to toggle off this whole group (see image), and when I toggle it on again, to only have the subgroups and layers checked that were checked before.

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: From QGIS 2.12 onwards, you can turn on your layers in a group, _right-click_ the group icon and enable the **Mutually Exclusive Group** option. Now when you toggle the group, all the layers you enabled beforehand will toggle on. _Note that this only works on a group-by-group basis, i.e. it won't work for subgroups_.

Comment: If it's only a matter of visualisation, i "offer" you a non-very elegant workaround, but useful (in my opinion): create duplicates of those layers you want to visualize at the same time and create a sub-group for them. This way, you can create as much visualisations as you want with the same layers. But be careful, if you edit the shape or the attributes of a layer, the duplicates will equally be edited. But you can edit its style differently if you want.

Comment: @Joseph: this works. However it only allows me to show one shapefile in a group at a time, which is not really what I was looking for. It will come in handy at some point though

Comment: Not sure this was ever solved? @Joseph, i tried your solution, but the Mutually Exclusive Group option seems to only allow one sub-item in a group to be selected - In my experience, if you select all the layers in a group, then make that Mutually Exclusive, it will de-select all but one.

Comment: @mike - Yes you're right, I guess I missed that! You could consider making a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) so that something like this could be implemented in a future iteration ;)